# Broadcast message to Parent Gameobject and Siblings in Unity

Tags: c#, unity

I wish to broadcast a message from one object to it's parent and it's siblings. I am aware that unity does not support broadcasting a message to all other game objects but is there a way to broadcast to parent and siblings?

I am using Unity 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, are you aware of the command [BroadcastMessage](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.BroadcastMessage.html)? It's not quite what you are asking for, but it's close and it happens to be named the exact terms you used. That command sends a message to all *children*, not siblings, but that means it will message all siblings if you use that command *on the parent.* So write something like:
transform.parent.BroadcastMessage("FunctionName");